# I want to retrieve the p-value from the arimax model of the statsmodels library

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I am creating a function for checking parameters of arimax model with the following data:

`Y = [3.817676, 6.51001, 4.406769, 6.119574, 8.135326, 9.344867, 9.147651, 8.101493, 10.14642, 11.0452, 10.12248, 9.973602, 10.62131, 10.08406, 10.34605, 7.892203, 11.20557, 12.45212, 13.50633, 11.73122]`

`X1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.5, 3.5, 3.0, 4.5, 5.0, 4.5, 8.0, 11.0, 7.0, 6.5, 8.5, 9.5, 15.0, 14.0, 12.0, 13.5, 16.5, 10.0]`

`X2 = [10.985, 11.895, 12.685, 13.58, 14.895, 15.7, 16.79, 17.475, 18.475, 19.58, 20.475, 21.37, 22.79, 23.475, 23.845, 23.12, 25.32, 27.895, 28.265, 29.685]`

with the results as shown in the picture

`model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(endog=data['Y'], exog=data[['X1','X2']],order=[1,1,1]).fit(disp=0)`

`print(model.summary())`

[image]

I want to remove the parameter with the most p-value and create a new model. The desired result is a model with p < 0.05.

please help me.

Comment: Have you tried the pvalues() method? https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.pvalues.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the p values with `model.pvalues`.

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.pvalues.html

Comment: thank you very much. Do you know how to remove const?

Comment: Can you tell me the class you are using? -> type(model) or the full name of the package that you import the class from? By the way, if you just want to check the p values you can see them in the "P>|z|" column.